# How does capybara/selenium grab current URL? Issue with single page site

Tags: ruby, url, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am using ruby and capybara(which leverages selenium) to automate walking through a website. After navigating to a new page I verify that the new page URL is what i'm expecting. My issue comes when I walk through an order funnel that is a single page but loads different views.

Some code...

I create my session instance then have additional code opening the browser and walking to a certain point in the website that I wont include

```
$session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
```

My line for checking the browser URL without search params ie: everything after '?'

```
if url == $session.current_url.to_s.split("?")[0]
        urlCorrect = true
end
```

This code works fine when my URL is

https://www.homepage.com

Then I click on a link that takes me to my order funnel ... https://www.homepage.com/order#/orderpage1?option1=something&option2=somethingelse

My function still matches the expected URL. But the issue comes when I move to the second page of the order funnel :

https://www.homepage.com/order#/orderpage2?option1=something&option2=somethingelse

My capybara code to get current url still returns the URL from orderpage1. Im guessing its because there is no postback when moving from orderpage1 to orderpage2 but i dont know how to force a postback or tell capybara to re-grab the url

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks

Quick Edit: I forgot to mention this behavior is only in IE. Chrome and Firefox both work correctly with the exact same code

Answer (score 1):

Capybara grabs the current_url by querying the browser - it doesn't cache it.  The issue you're probably running into is that clicking the link to move to the next page doesn't wait for the page change to happen, so if you call current_url before the page load has happened you'll still get the original url.  There are two solutions for that - 1. use capybara to look for content that doesn't appear until the new page is loaded ( have_content ), 2. use the has_current_path? method which will wait/retry for a period of time until the current_path/url match

```
$session.has_current_path?('expected path')
```

There are options if you want to match against the full url, and you can use a regex to match as well - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/SessionMatchers#has_current_path%3F-instance_method

Comment: Thanks for the input Tom. I did consider that I was grabbing the URL too quickly so I entered a breakpoint (pry) and gave it plenty of time to wait then manually checked the $session.current_url and it never grabs the correct one. I forgot to mention that this behavior is only in IE. When i run the same code with firefox or chrome browsers everything works fine.

Comment: Ah -- sounds like possibly an issue with the iedriverserver then

Comment: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/132 is people having the same issue but I don't find a report of it to the selenium/iedriver project

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tom Walpole for finding the bug report for this issue. This link sums up the root of the issue and provides a few workarounds if anyone else is encountering this issue.

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/132